# I can't open local Folder from link on Sharepoint website

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, internet-explorer-11, web-parts

i need help : i can't open local folder from hyperlink in webPart 'Script Editor'
    Simple Code : [a href='C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder']open folder[/a]
or like a link in Library. Any idea? 
weird things that is working on the another PC and not on mine.
I'am working with IE 11

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on the server this will work but for users that are not, the path will try to get the folder on their local machine. You might try to have a website in your IIS and put files in  a folder of a website. Then you might be able to link the folder (with URL (http or https), not by path) if the 'directory browsing' is enabled in your iis features.

You can find more info on directory browsing here: http://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-enable-directory-browsing-with-iis7-web-config

PS: this is not a SharePoint question...